# Calculate volume using Fubini's Theorem.

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find the volume of the region between $z=x^2+9y^2$ and $z=18-x^2-9y^2$ using Fubini's theorem.

Where do I begin and how do I proceed?

Comment: Some context please. Do you know how to do it without? Do you know Fubini's theorem? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Both surfaces are elliptical paraboloids, one opening down, the other one opening up. Can you tell what their intersection is?

Comment: Step one: understand the problem.  Step two: draw a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas for you to think about:

First, intersection of both surfaces:

$$x^2+9y^2=18-x^2-9y^2\implies x^2+9y^2=9\implies\frac{x^2}{3^2}+\frac{y^2}{1^2}=1$$

and we get an ellipse with $\;x,y\,-$ radiuses $\;3,1\;$ , resp. This means that when inputting, say $\,x=3,\;y=0\;$ (the rightmost hotizontal vertex of the ellipse when seen on the $\;xy\,-$ plane), if we input this in either of both surfaces we get $\;z=9\;$ , and we can thus calculate separately both volumes: the lower paraboloid's and the upper one's. For example, for the upper one:

$$V=\int_{-3}^3\int_{-1}^1\int_9^{18-x^2-9y^2}\mathrm d z\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x=\int_{-3}^3\int_{-1}^1\left(9-x^2-9y^2\right)\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x=$$

$$=4\int_0^3\int_0^1\left(9-x^2-9y^2\right)\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x=4\int_0^3(9-x^2-3)=4\left(6\cdot3-\frac{27}3\right)=36$$

Now you try the other part's volume (the lower paraboloid's), and then sum up.

By the way, I can't see any need in Fubini's theorem here...

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: we are computing a triple integral (volume) via iterated integrals and not some limit of sums of infinitesimal volumes; this is permitted by Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @AlexProvost Good point. I connect F.T. more with changing the order of integration than with iterated integrals, but I guess it is the whole thing.